# spresenseで取得した画像を外部モニターに表示させたい

Tags: spresense

Spresenseカメラボードを使用して画像の取得を行う場合、LCDではなく外部モニターに表示させる方法などありますでしょうか。

例えばbluetoothで接続できるとか，HDMIでモニターにつなげられるとか．

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

[5.2. multiwebcam サンプルアプリケーション](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html#_multiwebcam_%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3)というサンプルが公開されています。
拡張ボードを用いることでWi-Fi経由で画像を取得できるようです。